# Eclipselink Mysql Table name upper case

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, eclipselink

I have two entity classes Member and EvaluationType. They are relational tables.

Member :

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "evaluationId")
private EvaluationType evaluationType;
```

Evaluation Type :

```
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "evaluationType", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 private List<Member> memberList;
```

When I run the application I am getting following error :

Error Code: 1215
Call: ALTER TABLE MEMBER ADD CONSTRAINT FK_MEMBER_evaluationId FOREIGN KEY (evaluationId) REFERENCES EVALUATİONTYPE (evaluationId)
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="ALTER TABLE MEMBER ADD CONSTRAINT FK_MEMBER_evaluationId FOREIGN KEY (evaluationId) REFERENCES EVALUATİONTYPE (evaluationId)")

Error is "EVALUATİONTYPE" table name. Because There is no upper case table name in mysql. HOw can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have EvaluationType annotated with the table name(@Table)?

Comment: @Table (name = "EvaluationType ") works, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to set case sensitivity in database itself. Check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html
lower_case_table_names=1 will store all table names in lowercase and make name comparison to be not case sensitive.
But @Table annotation shall work too. So it's up to you.